# Sending an object from the server to the client (node/express/ejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I need to access the user object in my view.

In my server code, I have:

```
res.render("profile.ejs", { user: userObj });
```

...where userObj is a nice key-value object with all my data.

In my EJS file, I have something like:

```
<h5 class="userName"><%= user.firstname %> <%= user.lastname %></h5>
```

...which is not printing anything.

I know that it's not working because it's trying to convert my userObj to a string, and that I need to do something like "user: JSON.stringify(userObj)" instead, but then how do I access it like an object in my view?

--

**UPDATE:**

All of this code was actually fine. I'm silly & glazed over the fact my database query was incorrect.

I thought it was:
`{ name: 'name', blah: 'blah' }`

But it was: `{ key: {name: 'name', blah: 'blah'} }`

and I didn't notice.

Answer (score 3):

Double check for typos and uppercase/lowercase issues.
You can print the content of your object using this:

```
var util = require('util');
console.log(util.inspect(userObj));
```

You dont have to convert your json to string to pass it to view. It should work with json. you can even print a json in express and ejs. it should print all of the key value pairs in your json recursively.

In normal configuration, you could do that.

```
var userObj = {
    firstname: 'Name',
    lastname: 'anything'
};
res.render("profile.ejs", { user: userObj });
```

and in your view

```
<h5 class="userName"><%= user.firstname %> <%= user.lastname %></h5>
```

Comment: Hmm, not letting me. If it helps - when I print <%= user %> it's just "[object Object]" :(

Comment: Why dont you use `<%- JSON.stringify(user) %>`?

Comment: Shoot, you're right and I just made a completely different, irrelevant mistake! Okay, updating my question --